# How to correct for acidic water when taking the pH of a soil/water solution?

Tags: water, ph

I work in a soil science lab and not very much a chemist.

Recently I took the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a large number of soil samples using a glass electrode on a mixture of $\pu{10 g}$ soil and $\pu{20 mL}$ Millipore water. Partway through the assay, I discovered that the water I was using had a $\mathrm{pH}$ of $\pu{5.2}$.

Is there a way to correct my recorded $\mathrm{pH}$'s to values I would have measured had the water had a $\mathrm{pH} = 7$?

Comment: I also know the water concentration of each soil sample if that helps

Comment: There should be a standard procedure for this analysis. The procedure would include how to handle the distilled water. An educated guess is that $\ce{CO2}$ from the atmosphere is causing the low pH. (I remember boiling water and then putting a drying tube filled with $\ce{NaOH}$ on the container's headspace for some experiment that I did.)   Also the procedure should detail how to handle the soil-water mixture. If the soil has a pH above 5 or so, then the soil-water mixture too will eventually react with  $\ce{CO2}$ from the atmosphere.

Comment: The pH is not as important as the quantity of acid. When I have done similar tests , i assumed the several grams of soil had much more material to affect the pH than the water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regrettably, one cannot simply add or subtract pH to correct for that error. Correction would depend on knowing *how much* and *what type* of each contaminant was in the water.

For example, a *very dilute*, [0.00001 molar solution](https://socratic.org/questions/how-to-calculate-ph-of-hcl), of $\ce{HCl}$ would have pH about 5. It would take [considerably more dissolved $\ce{CO2}$](http://home.pcisys.net/%7Ebestwork.1/CO2Water/WaterCa_HTML.html) to lower the pH to 5. The first would likely have less effect on your measurements, because the actual *amount* of $\ce{HCl}$ would have been small, but in the second case, far more $\ce{CO2}$ would be present to react with the soil sample.

Comment: Ah well, back to pH-measuring then. Thanks for answering!

Comment: We often acid-wash our containers in HCl in our lab. If the contaminant *were* enough HCl to lower the water pH to 5.2, how would I correct my pHs?

Comment: @Tillandsia123, How much water is left in the containers? If a 10 liter carboy were rinsed with HCl and shaken out, and if a 1 ml pipette were rinsed with HCl and shaken out, is that the same amount of remnant HCl? Answer: rinse with *pure* H2O, shake out, rinse, shake out, reiterate until the pH approaches that of the "pure" water. In other words, establish how much rinsing is needed, measuring pH each time, and establish a routine so that you need not repeat those tests. Even then, if the detergent or water source changes, you'd need you'd check again.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that. Thank you!